# Multithreading with events in WPF

Tags: c#, multithreading, object, events

UPDATE:
As mentioned in the comments section the problem was solved, but I do not understand why my way of implementation was wrong.

I have this situation:

I have a device which can be triggered with an event in my WPF project.
This event pulls Data from my device at a polling rate of 1ms. I want to process
the data in different threads.

My approach was, to start a backgroundworker which registers the device event (I read events run on the thread they are called from). In the device event itself the data is saved to an object, which is declared in my form. After that the labels in the WPF form a are refreshed with a Invoke Method.

This happens until someone presses cancel on a button in my form, which unregisters the device event and stops the thread.

Here is some code I use:

Declaration in my Main Window:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        private MeasureObject mObject = new MeasureObject();
    ... }
```

This is my initialization:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            this.worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
            this.worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;


        }
```

If this button is press i run my background worker:

```
  private void btnStartMeasure_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            this.worker.RunWorkerAsync();

        }
```

Here I register my event for the device. It should now run on my worker thread. I tried to declare the event itself here too, but it did not work, so I placed it in my main windows.

```
        private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

            this.myController.ControlCenter.Diagnostics.NewDiagPacketArrived += new EventHandler<NewDiagPacketArrivedEventArgs>(Diagnostics_NewDiagPacketArrived);
            // run all background tasks here
        }
```

This is not needed and empty. The worker is only cancelled if the user sets it on cancel.

```
        private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,
                                               RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

This event is triggered in my Window and calls two functions, it should run on the backgroundworker if I am correct.

```
private void Diagnostics_NewDiagPacketArrived(object sender, NewDiagPacketArrivedEventArgs e)
        {


            try
            {

                Measure(e);
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( new Action(() => { SetStates(e); }),System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Input);

            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

Measure gets the e Object from the device and saves it to a Dataobject i created

```
 private void Measure(NewDiagPacketArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            lock(this.mObject)
            {
                this.mObject.ID = this.list.Count;
                ....

               this.list.Add(this.mObject);


            }
   }
```

SetStates refreshed the GUI

```
private void SetStates(NewDiagPacketArrivedEventArgs e)
        {



            lock(this.mObject)
            {

                this.lblID.Content = this.mObject.ID;


            }

        }
```

The problem with my code is if I cancel the event and the thread with this code:

```
private void btnStopMeasure_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            this.myController.ControlCenter.Diagnostics.NewDiagPacketArrived -= Diagnostics_NewDiagPacketArrived;
            this.worker.CancelAsync();

        }
```

And try to get the list where I added my objects, all objects have the same ID's and values. It seems like as soon as I unregister the event or press the stop measure button, all mObjects in my list get overwritten with the mObject at the time when I unregister the event.

so my list looks like this:

```
list[0].ID = 1
list[1].ID = 1
list[2].ID = 1
```

rather than this:

```
list[0].ID = 1
list[1].ID = 2
list[2].ID = 3
```

Maybe you can help?

Comment: BackgroundWorker is a Winforms component, for WPF you should probably use `Task.Run` and a `IProgress<T>` object to report progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not creating a new instance of the mObject - you only create one of them here:

private MeasureObject mObject = new MeasureObject();

Your code then adds the SAME object to the list, and updates that. You need to make a new object each time and put it in the list.

```
this.mObject.ID = this.list.Count;
                ....

               this.list.Add(this.mObject);
```

Currently your list is a list of the same object.

Comment: Why do I have to do that. I initialize one mObject at the beginning of my form. Each time the event is triggered mObject.ID is set to a new value, because with each iteration this.list.Count gets higher by 1. So first i add the mObject with an ID of 0 to my list, after that the same mObject with ID 1 and so on. I do not get why I have to initialize a new object with each iteration. (Btw I did it and it worked, I just do not understand why....)

Comment: No problem - When you initialize a new object (a new "instance") this is called a "reference type" - you reserve a new area in memory which represents the state of that object. So, that specific "instance" has it's own area to store it's own values. ID is one of those values which belongs to that "instance". So unless you make a new instance you are just overwriting the same area in memory. Now given that, the next thing you need to know is that adding an "instance" to a List does not make a copy - it stores a "reference" to that "instance".

Comment: This would be different if you added a "value" type to the List instead of a "reference" type - they don't work in the same way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I understand!